# Find the equation of the circle circumscribing the triangle formed by the three points $(a,0,0)$, $(0,b,0)$ and $(0,0,c)$.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d, spheres

Assuming the equation of the circle circumscribing the triangle formed by the three given points is given by the sphere through the three points and the plane through the three points.

Plane is given by $\frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} + \frac{z}{c} = 1$
and assuming the equation of the sphere is $x^2+y^2+z^2+2ux+2vy+2wz+d=0$.

I've not been able to find the value for $d$, putting the three points in the equation of sphere I got $3$ equations with $4$ variables.

Comment: There is more than one sphere going through three given points in space. However, every single sphere intersects the plane in the same circle.

Comment: Yeah, true thats why I'm not able to fix a value for d.

Comment: One sphere that goes through them all is $x(x-a)+y(y-b)+z(z-c)=0$

Comment: @Michael Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: the $d$ will come from the radius of the sphere, which can be a sphere for which the circumscribing circle is a great circle, and you can find that radius using one of the many identities involving sides of a triangle and its other quantities

Comment: just plug in $(a,0,0)$ etc. and see that they all satisfy it

Comment: @NickPavlov which identity you are referring to, I could not think of any way to find the radius!

Comment: I think Michael's way is easier, but there are many involving $R$, for example $S = abc/4R$ where $a,b,c$ are the sides (not the things in your set-up), and the area $S$ is also calculable from the sides using Heron's formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula

Comment: What form of equation are you supposed to find? Since this is a space curve, you’ll need either a system of equations that give it implicitly, which is what it looks like you’re going for, or a set of parametric equations that specify the curve directly.

Comment: The centers of these spheres lie on the line common to the planes that bisect vertex pairs. The center of the circle will be the intersection of this line and the triangle’s plane.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's work out the plane of the circle.

The three triangle vertices are
$$\vec{a} = \left [ \begin{array}{c} a \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right ], \qquad \vec{b} = \left [ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ b \\ 0 \end{array} \right ], \qquad \vec{c} = \left [ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \\ c \end{array} \right ] \tag{1}\label{na1}$$
The equation for the plane is
$$\vec{p} \cdot \vec{n} - d = 0$$
where the plane normal $\vec{n}$ is 
$$\vec{n} = ( \vec{b} - \vec{a} ) \times ( \vec{c} - \vec{a} ) = \left [ \begin{array}{c} -a \\ b \\ 0 \end{array} \right ] \times \left [ \begin{array}{c} -a \\ 0 \\ c \end{array} \right ] = \left [ \begin{array}{c} b c \\ a c \\ a b \end{array} \right ]$$
and the distance from plane to origin $d$ is the same at all points on the plane, including the vertices,
$$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{n} = \vec{b} \cdot \vec{n} = \vec{c} \cdot \vec{n} = a b c$$
i.e., the full equation of the plane is
$$\vec{p} \cdot \vec{n} - a b c = 0, \qquad \vec{n} = \left [ \begin{array}{c} b c \\ a c \\ a b \end{array} \right ] \tag{2}\label{na2}$$

Now, one way to treat the circle is to treat it as a great circle of a sphere that passes through the points. The key point is that because it is a great circle, the center of the sphere must be on the same plane as the vertices.

This also means that we can use two coordinates, say $u$ and $v$, to describe the center of the circle (and sphere):
$$\vec{p} = \vec{a} + u ( \vec{b} - \vec{a} ) + v (\vec{c} - \vec{a}) \tag{3}\label{na3}$$
If the radius of the circle (and therefore the radius of the sphere) is $r$, then we have a system of equations,
$$\begin{cases}
\left \lVert \vec{p} - \vec{a} \right \rVert^2 = r^2 \\
\left \lVert \vec{p} - \vec{b} \right \rVert^2 = r^2 \\
\left \lVert \vec{p} - \vec{c} \right \rVert^2 = r^2
\end{cases}$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}
\left \lVert u ( \vec{b} - \vec{a} ) + v (\vec{c} - \vec{a}) \right \rVert^2 - r^2 = 0 \\
\left \lVert u ( \vec{b} - \vec{a} ) + v (\vec{c} - \vec{a}) + \vec{a} - \vec{b} \right \rVert^2 - r^2 = 0 \\
\left \lVert u ( \vec{b} - \vec{a} ) + v (\vec{c} - \vec{a}) + \vec{a} - \vec{c} \right \rVert^2 - r^2 = 0
\end{cases} \tag{4}\label{na4}$$

This system of equations has two solutions, one of which has a negative radius $r$; thus only one solution that makes sense:
$$\begin{cases}
u = \frac{a^2 b^2 + b^2 c^2}{2 (a^2 b^2 + a^2 c^2 + b^2 c^2)} \\
v = \frac{a^2 c^2 + b^2 c^2}{2 (a^2 b^2 + a^2 c^2 + b^2 c^2)} \\
r = \sqrt{\frac{(a^2 + b^2)(a^2 + c^2)(b^2 + c^2)}{4 (a^2 b^2 + a^2 c^2 + b^2 c^2 )}} \tag{5}\label{na5}\end{cases}$$
To find the center $\vec{p}$ in Cartesian coordinates, insert $u$ and $v$ and $\eqref{na1}$ to $\eqref{na3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Given the points

$$
\cases{
A=(a,0,0)\\
B=(0,b,0)\\
C=(0,0,c)\\
p = (x,y,z)
}
$$

the sphere center $p_0$ is determined by the intersection of plane $\Pi$ with the line $L$ such that

$$
\cases{
\Pi\to (p-A)\cdot\vec n=0\\
\vec n = (A-B)\times(B-C)\\
L\to \left((p-\frac{A+B}{2})\cdot(A-B)=0\right)\cap \left((p-\frac{A+C}{2})\cdot(A-C)=0\right)\\
L\to p=(0,\frac{b^2-a^2}{2b},\frac{c^2-a^2}{2c})+\lambda(1,\frac ab,\frac ac)
}
$$

then

$$
p_0 = \frac{1}{2(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2 c^2)}\left(a^3 \left(b^2+c^2\right),b^3 \left(a^2+c^2\right),c^3\left(a^2+b^2\right)\right)
$$

and

$$
r = \|p_0-A\| = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\left(a^2+b^2\right) \left(a^2+c^2\right) \left(b^2+c^2\right)}{a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2 c^2}}
$$

Attached a plot for $a=1,b=2,c=3$. In pink the plane $(p-A)\cdot \vec n=0$. In green the plane $(p-\frac{A+B}{2})\cdot(A-B)=0$ and in yellow the plane $(p-\frac{A+C}{2})\cdot(A-C)=0$. In red the line $p=(0,\frac{b^2-a^2}{2b},\frac{c^2-a^2}{2c})+\lambda(1,\frac ab,\frac ac)$

[image]